# Angular 2 Routes Options

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and Node JS and I am currently working on an application, which I have come up short when deciding how to best navigate between my different components.

[Users are able to add the name of a user, and add books associated to that user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT5sI.png)

Upon clicking a book name, I wish to navigate to a component associated with that book, pulling information specifically that entry, such as comments.

[Component that will render specific book information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRWoQ.png)

Using Angular 2 (MEAN stack), I would like to understand how I should address such a problem - Should I be storing any specific values to make it easier both to navigate and pull the information about the book from the database.

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="author">
                 {{ author.fullName }}
            </div>
            <div class="addbook">
                <book-input [author]='author'></book-input>
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div>
            <ul *ngFor="let book of author.books"> 
                <li><a [routerLink]="['book']">{{ book }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </footer>
</article>
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I cannot see your screenshots link it says `503` error

Comment: Thanks for your email, strange - I've reuploaded

Comment: please try not to tag both Angular and Angularjs in the same question;  Despite their obviously confusing names, they are completely different frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to add an id to the end of your router link, so it routes to something like book/thebookid.

Then you'd add something in your Routing module like so :

```
{path: 'book/:id, component: BookComponent}
```

Then in your book component, you'd want to look for that id in the URL and tell it to fetch the book from your service.  You'll want to import a few things to make it happen.

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
```

Then in your constructor you have to instantiate some of those :

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

You'll actually probably want to import OnInit from '@angular/core' too, so it runs the logic required to initialized the component.  So add this to the top of the component as well.

```
 import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
```

And make sure your component implements it when you declare it

```
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {...}
```

Then in your component, declare your ngOnInit method, and then inside that you can have your logic for getting the book from the API:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.params && this.route.snapshot.params['id']) { // make sure id is present
        bookService.getBookById(this.route.snapshot.params[id).subscribe((res)=>{
          this.book = res.json(); // this is just an example of where to put your call, not how to make it
 } else {
//no id received, throw error whatever you need, show blank form etc
}
```